# How can I link portals from own faction without portal key in ingress?

Tags: ingress

There are many portals in my area belonging to my faction, and I want to link them.

According to [this page](http://support.google.com/ingress/answer/2808251?hl=en&ref_topic=2799270) I must hold the portal key for the destination portal in my inventory.

How can I get the portal key for a portal belonging to my own faction?

*Or*, more generally, how can I link friendly portals that I don't have portal keys for?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You have to go there and *hack* the (destination) portal to obtain the key (yes, you need to hack "friendly" portals anyway to get supplies), or trade keys with team members by dropping/acquiring them.

Also, resonators "drop" keys which are used for links when one end is blown up that you can pick up.

Comment: Does hacking a friendly portal not cause it (or me!) any damage?

Comment: @agryson no it does not harm the portal, even does not drain energy from it.

Comment: I found this highly relevant Google Document that explains all of the basics for any other beginners: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ZKt6bvgcsS4Bzve8k36FZNmAYrwt8QrSn-wztNpOkhU/preview?sle=true#

Answer (score 13):

The only way to link two portals is to have a portal key form the **destination portal**.

There are only two ways to get a portal key right now:

- Hack a portal (actually hacking in #ingress is just a search for goodies)
- Pick up a key lying on the ground (a key can be dropped by another player or fell out of the portal as a result of a powerful xmp blast)

Official info is here: http://support.google.com/ingress/answer/2808251?hl=en&ref_topic=2799270